# Ruby setting ENV variables on a mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, macos

I would like to try an keep my development machine as close as the production server (heroku in this case).

Heroku lets you define config vars ie.

```
config:add key=val
```

This is now pretty secure as secret key values are not stored in my code.

Do you know how and where can I create such environment variables per app on my local mac machine.

I have googled this and as of yet not found a good solution. Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks Zabba, But I have actually found a great way for me.

I am using [POW](http://pow.cx/manual.html#section_2.2) to run my local apps and reading the docs I have found out that you can set Environment Vars by adding a .powenv file in the root of my app ie.

```
export API_KEY='abcdef123456'
```

You can then use in your app like normal ie.

```
api_key = ENV['API_KEY']
```

Pretty kool stuff.

Comment: Well, you didn't mention you were using POW!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way:

Go to http://railswizard.org/ and add only "EnvYAML" to the template. Click finish and then click on the generated `.rb` file. See how that code is using a file `config/env.yml` to set ENV vars.

Here is how it is done, thanks to http://railswizard.org/:

In your app's directory:

Append in `config/application.rb`:

```
require 'env_yaml'
```

Create a file called `lib/env_yaml.rb`:

```
require 'yaml'
begin
  env_yaml = YAML.load_file(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../config/env.yml')
  if env_hash = env_yaml[ENV['RACK_ENV'] || ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || 'development']
    env_hash.each_pair do |k,v|
      ENV[k] = v.to_s
    end
  end
rescue StandardError => e
end
```

Create a file called `config/env.yml`:

```
defaults: &defaults
  ENV_YAML: true
  some_key: value

development:
  <<: *defaults

test:
  <<: *defaults

production:
  <<: *defaults
```

Note that ENV is not a `Hash` - it only appears so because of the use of `[]`. That is why in `lib/env_yaml.rb` an `each` loop is setting in ENV the value of each value found in the `config/env.yml` - because we cannot assign a `Hash` directly to `ENV`.

Comment: The idea behind ENV vars is that you can keep your environment variables out of your code and they are magically available to you from inside your app. This solution proposes to hardcode it again exposing your settings for everyone to see.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not using pow but rvm and bash.  I was able to set environmental variables by following the instructions at [this Peachpit blog post](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=31442&seqNum=3).

Like the other answers, I had to add commands like `export TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID="XXX"`but to my ~/.profile file.

Then, accessed the variables in my code with:

```
account_sid = ENV["TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your environment variables in a `.env` file and `foreman` will pick them up automatically.